# Determinants and diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I know that if the $det(A) = 0$, then it is not invertible. But does that mean it is also undiagonalizable? What do the other pieces of information, $det(A+2I) = 0$, $det(A-3I) = 0$ tell me?

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ has determinant zero. Is it not diagonalizable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**: If $\text{det}(A-\lambda I) = 0$ for some number $\lambda$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

The rank of $A$ is also the number of non-zero eigenvalues (counting multiplicity).

Comment: So in this case, $A$ has 2 distinct eigenvalues, so the rank will be 2, and so the answer is III only?

Comment: Yes, the rank of $A$ is $2$. However, since $\det(A-0I) = \det(A) = 0$, we have that $0$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Ohh... those are some good hints. Thanks!